# Extending RapidMiner using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, rapidminer

Using the `How to extend rapidminer` guide, I am trying to make an extension to rapidminer 5.3.

1. I downloaded the rapidminer source code from `https://github.com/rapidminer/rapidminer` into a zip file in my local drive.
2. I exported it into eclipse as a git project.

**Issue:** I am seeing errors in the rapidminer Project indicated with a red cross. But I cannot see any errors in the folders.

3. Downloaded rapidminer extension template and tutorial from these locations. [Extension tutorial](https://github.com/rapidminer/rapidminer-extension-tutorial) and [Extension Template](https://github.com/rapidminer/rapidminer-extension-tutorial).
4. Imported them into Eclipse. (Tutorial suggests importing as Gradle projects. But, I am getting errors while doing this.
5. Added RapidMiner project into the Build path of other projects. Now, all projects show a red cross mark.

What is going wrong?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue, I wasn't able to import the tutorial Gradle project. It seems that it's because of the Gradle configuration file.
It also seems that the official documentations for RapidMiner are currently out of date and doesn't even mention how to set up Gradle. [[1]](http://rapid-i.com/rapidforum/index.php?topic=8627.0;wap2)

According to the [following GitHub commit](https://github.com/rapidminer/rapidminer-extension-template/commit/8ec8823baa71c61b0d2d5fd14b2a4291a4555476) on the RapidMiner Extension Template project, the 0.7.x RapidMiner Gradle plugin is not available.
If you change the `build.gradle` file in your cloned tutorial project according to the GitHub commit above, you will be able to import it to Eclipse via Gradle.

I was able to cope this issue with the following steps:

1. Made sure that Gradle was installed properly and the environment variables are set (`GRADLE_HOME` was set up, and `%GRADLE_HOME%/bin` was added to the `PATH`).
2. Modified the `build.gradle` config file.
   Replaced this section:

   ```
   buildscript {
     dependencies {
       classpath 'com.rapidminer.gradle:extension:0.7.+'
     }
   }
   ```

   With the following:

   ```
   plugins {
     id 'com.rapidminer.extension' version '0.6.2'
   }
   ```
3. Pointed the `rapidminerHome` variable in `build.gradle` file to the root directory of a debuggable RapidMiner instance.

   ```
   extensionConfig {

     // ... other config values

     // set the root path of the debuggable RapidMiner
     rapidminerHome = '../rapidminer-studio'

     // ... other config values
   }
   ```
4. Executed the `installExtension` Gradle task, either from the Eclipse Gradle plugin or either from command line ( `gradle installExtension` ).

Hope this helps.